# Error when making a decision surface graph on a decision tree

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

My version of python is 3.
I have adapted [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_iris_dtc.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-iris-dtc-py) code for my data.
And when trying to make the graph, on the line

```py
X = l_atributos[:, pair]
```

I have the error:

> list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

But I'm not seeing where the problem is. Could you help me?

```py
for pairidx, pair in enumerate([[0, 1],[0, 2],[0, 3],[1, 2],[1, 3],[2, 3]]):
    # We only take the two corresponding features
    X = l_atributos[:, pair]
    y = etiquetas

    # Train
    clf = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(X, y)

    # Plot the decision boundary
    plt.subplot(2, 3, pairidx + 1)

    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, plot_step),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, plot_step))
    plt.tight_layout(h_pad=0.5, w_pad=0.5, pad=2.5)

    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    cs = plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu)

    plt.xlabel(['so2', 'no2', 'temp', 'viento', 'precipitacion'][pair[0]])
    plt.ylabel(['so2', 'no2', 'temp', 'viento', 'precipitacion'][pair[1]])

    # Plot the training points
    for i, color in zip(range(n_classes), plot_colors):
        idx = np.where(y == i)
        plt.scatter(X[idx, 0], X[idx, 1], c=color, label=['nivel 0', 'nivel 1', 'nivel 2', 'nivel 3'][i], cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu, edgecolor='black', s=15)

plt.suptitle("Decision surface of a decision tree using paired features")
plt.legend(loc='lower right', borderpad=0, handletextpad=0)
plt.axis("tight")

plt.figure()
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(l_atributos, etiquetas)
plot_tree(clf, filled=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Provide the full code. As I can see you've already updated it but I cannot see `l_atributos` declaration.

Comment: l_atributos   
are the attributes to generate the tree. Next I show the first 3:
Comand:

`` `python
    print(l_atributos[:3]) 
`` ` 

Result: 

`` `python
    [['66', '26.0', '12.1', '16.0', '0.0'], ['75', '16.0', '10.0', '26.0', '5.9'], ['61', '25.0', '8.0', '23.0', '29.4']]
`` `
To generate the tree, classify and train it I haven't had any problems. Even I have been able to make the graph of the tree

Comment: I'm sorry, this is the first time I've done a post and I don't know how to put the formats. If you don't understand it well, tell me and I'll include it in the post code.
Thank you

Comment: For example with the first value of l_atributos (['66', '26.0', '12.1', '16.0', '0.0']).  'so2' = '66' // 'no2' = '26.0' // 'temp' = '12.1' // 'viento' = '16.0' // 'precipitacion' = '0.0'

Comment: is my answer helpful or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common problem in data structures used to represent the data in the example and your code.

If you print the content of `iris` example you may see next data:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
print(iris.data)
```

*output*

```py
array([[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
...
```

As you can see this is the 2D array was wrapped with `numpy.array(...)` wrapper.

But in your example you have just 2D array:

```py
print(l_atributos[:3])
```

*result*

```py
[['66', '26.0', '12.1', '16.0', '0.0'], ['75', '16.0', '10.0', '26.0', '5.9'], ['61', '25.0', '8.0', '23.0', '29.4']]
```

If you want to use scikit's example with minimum changes just wrap your data with `numpy.array`:

```py
import numpy as np
l_atributos = np.array([['66', '26.0', '12.1', '16.0', '0.0'], ['75', '16.0', '10.0', '26.0', '5.9'], ['61', '25.0', '8.0', '23.0', '29.4']])
```